# Programmatically register a TFS server in Visual Studio?

Tags: powershell, tfs, visual-studio-2017

As part of an initialization script for a new development machine I want to register our on-premise tfs server instance in Visual Studio.
That is, I want the following information to be specified programmatically, perhaps through the registry or by changing a Visual Studio config file:

So far I haven't been able to figure this out, does anybody know how?

[image: Visual Studio: Connect to a Project dialog]

Comment: any updates? I've got the same task and would like to do it using TeamFoundation assemblies from PowerShell.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that this can be done fully automated, because the user needs to be authenticated. I think you should use the `TeamProjectPicker` dialog. You can find this class inside the `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client` assembly.

`$picker = New-Object Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TeamProjectPicker([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TeamProjectPickerMode]::MultiProject, $false)
$result = $picker.ShowDialog()`

You can find several more powershell / TFS examples [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alming/2013/03/07/using-powershell-and-tfs-api-to-list-users-in-tfs-2010-and-2012/)

Comment: I'm not fully convinced, I don't think adding the server name itself would require authentication, but only when you start accessing it. Still, thanks for your code fragment.